# Internal Server Error

Tags: php

Soy nuevo en PHP y estaba haciendo un formulario en este mismo pero cuando agrego información a la base de datos me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mas extraño es que me inserta los datos en la base de datos y cuando actualizo la pagina me vuelve a insertar los datos. Cabe resaltar que utilizo 3 archivos php: index.php, insertar.php (este archivo es donde inserto los datos) y datos_conexion.php(este archivo es donde estan los datos para la conexión hacia la base de datos).
Otro dato es que estoy utilizando Xampp para el servidor Apache y MySQL Workbench para la base de datos.

Este es el código del archivo donde inserto los datos

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["btn_agregar"])){
        include("datos_conexion.php");
        $db_conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usr,$db_pass,$db_name,$db_puerto);
        $txt_codigo=utf8_decode($_POST["txt_codigo"]);
        $txt_nombres=utf8_decode($_POST["txt_nombres"]);
        $txt_apellidos=utf8_decode($_POST["txt_apellidos"]);
        $txt_direccion=utf8_decode($_POST["txt_direccion"]);
        $txt_telefono=utf8_decode($_POST["txt_telefono"]);
        $drop_puesto=utf8_decode($_POST["drop_puesto"]);
        $txt_fn=utf8_decode($_POST["txt_fn"]);
        $sql= "INSERT INTO empleados(codigo,nombres,apellidos,direccion,telefono,fecha_de_nacimiento,id_puesto)VALUES ('".$txt_codigo."','".$txt_nombres."','".$txt_apellidos."','".$txt_direccion."','".$txt_telefono."','".$txt_fn."',".$drop_puesto.")";
        if($db_conexion -> query($sql) === true){
            $db_conexion -> close();
            echo "Exito";
            header('Location : index.php');

        }else{
            echo "Error" . $sql."<br>".$db_conexion -> close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Este es el código de los datos para la conexión hacia la base de datos

```
<?php
  $db_host ="localhost";
  $db_usr ="usr_empresa";
  $db_pass ="Empres@123";
  $db_name ="db_empresa";
  $db_puerto ="3307";
?>
```

Revisando los logs del xampp encontre lo siguiente

> [http:error] [pid 13092:tid 1868] [client ::1:62630] AH02429: Response header name 'Location ' contains invalid characters, aborting request, referer: http://localhost/empresa_php/

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero des un vistazo al log; o habilitalo para que "caches" el error de manera más puntual.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr ya revise los logs y edite la pregunta con el error que encontré .

Comment: Saludos. Según (esta en inglés) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873865/internal-server-error-while-navigating-php-pages el error es por el espacio que hay en **Location :** según debe ser **Location:**.

Comment: Si era eso, gracias por la ayuda.